# react native hover effect module not working properly in dynamic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, module

I trying to make a **onPress hover effect** to show text, when I click on image it will show me a text layer on my image, as its working fine for **one image & text**, but while making dynamic.. clicked on one image then that effect, affecting to all images with text.
**simply I want to show on single click show one text related to img, on different images on click show different text related to that images.**
how can fix it..

**App.js**

```
import Button from "../custom-components/Button";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Image,
  ImageBackground,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  Touchable,
  View,
  FlatList,
} from "react-native";
import { ScrollView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { BottomTabBarHeightCallbackContext } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import axios from "axios";
import { API_URL } from "@env";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function App() {
  const languageState = useSelector((state) => state.languageReducer);
  const [xx43d, setxx43d] = React.useState(languageState.language);
  const [showText, setShowText] = useState(false);
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${API_URL}/xyxsnn?xx43d=${xx43d}`)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setApiData(response.data.result);
        }
      })
      .catch((errors) => {
        console.log(errors);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <ScrollView>
        <FlatList
          data={apiData}
          numColumns={2}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <>
              <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={0.5}
                onPress={() => setShowText(!showText)}
              >
                <ImageBackground
                  source={{ uri: "https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png" }}
                  resizeMode="cover"
                  style={styles.image}
                >
                  {!!showText && <Text style={styles.text}>{item.name}</Text>}
                </ImageBackground>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </>
          )}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  image: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    height: 250,
    width: 170,
    margin: 12,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },

  text: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#000",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make Item a seprate component which has its own `showText` state.

Like

```
import Button from "../custom-components/Button";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Image,
  ImageBackground,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  Touchable,
  View,
  FlatList,
} from "react-native";
import { ScrollView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { BottomTabBarHeightCallbackContext } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import axios from "axios";
import { API_URL } from "@env";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function App() {
  const languageState = useSelector((state) => state.languageReducer);
  const [xx43d, setxx43d] = React.useState(languageState.language);
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${API_URL}/xyxsnn?xx43d=${xx43d}`)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setApiData(response.data.result);
        }
      })
      .catch((errors) => {
        console.log(errors);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <ScrollView>
        <FlatList
          data={apiData}
          numColumns={2}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Item data={item}/>}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </>
  );
}

const Item = ({data}) => {
  const [showText, setShowText] = useState(false);

  return(<TouchableOpacity
    activeOpacity={0.5}
    onPress={() => setShowText(!showText)}
  >
    <ImageBackground
      source={{ uri: "https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png" }}
      resizeMode="cover"
      style={styles.image}
    >
      {showText && <Text style={styles.text}>{data.name}</Text>}
    </ImageBackground>
  </TouchableOpacity>)
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  image: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    height: 250,
    width: 170,
    margin: 12,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },

  text: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#000",
  },
});
```